# If a cell within a range contains certain text then add text to another cell

Tags: excel, vba

How do I detect whether within a range of cells there exists a certain word in many sentences?

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set Rng = Range("Z10:Z35")
    certaintext = "Pc Owner"
        
    For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
        If Cell.Value Like "*" & certaintext & "*" Then
            Range("AF10") = "DONE"
        End If
    Next
            
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

I tried the same code in normal sub without `worksheet_change` and it works.

How do I activate this VBA code any time the worksheet changes?

Comment: You are either using the wrong event or the wrong column. This event triggers on a manual change in a range i.e. if `lookup_value` is a cell in this worksheet and you are manually changing it (without a formula) you could try its column. Share the `XLOOKUP` formula so we can try to fix it since there are other issues with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with InStr function.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim txt As String
    
    If Not target.Address = "$AF$10" Then
    
        Set Rng = Range("Z10:Z35")
        certaintext = "Pc Owner"
            
            For Each cl In Rng
                txt = cl.Value
                If InStr(1, txt, certaintext, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then Range("AF10") = "DONE"
            Next
            
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried but it doesn't work, maybe its because range Z10:Z35 are context returned by xlookup function?

Comment: are you getting any error or just no value in AF10?

Comment: just no value in AF10

Comment: I guess it could be because of the Application.EnableEvents is set to False. Try set it again to True and then use the code that I just updated. Using the target.address will prevent an infinite loop without turning off the events.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the update code! it worked really well, I find the instr() function much more precise and useful than the like function I previously used.

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Calculate: Update Column

- You cannot use the Worksheet Change event if your cells contain formulas. If you can identify the column that is triggering the change in the formulas via manual entry, use this column in a Worksheet Change event.
- Otherwise, you could use the Worksheet Calculate event but keep in mind that it triggers on each calculation which could slow down your worksheet.
- A proper solution would require more complications e.g. involving a public array variable that would hold the values of the column and on each calculation check if any of the values have changed and only then run a modified version of the posted procedure (`UpdateMyColumn`). The Worksheet Open event would also need to be included to initially populate the public array.
- The code is lightning fast which may not be enough because it will run too many times. Give it a try and share some feedback.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    UpdateMyColumn Me
End Sub

Sub UpdateMyColumn(ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    
    Const SRC_COLUMN_RANGE As String = "Z10:Z35" ' more than one cell!
    Const SRC_MATCH As String = "Pc Owner"
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "AF"
    Const DST_YES_STRING As String = "DONE"
    Const DST_NO_STRING As String = ""
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range(SRC_COLUMN_RANGE)
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = srg.Value
    
    Dim r As Long, IsMatch As Boolean
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        IsMatch = InStr(1, CStr(Data(r, 1)), SRC_MATCH, vbTextCompare) > 0
        Data(r, 1) = IIf(IsMatch, DST_YES_STRING, DST_NO_STRING)
    Next r
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        srg.EntireRow.Columns(DST_COLUMN).Value = Data
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: HI, thanks for the great advise, the code worked!  I tried several times and the calculation time does't seem to slow down so I guess this works for me.